# How can I install Open Office on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer?

Tags: dpkg, openoffice.org

I've followed this guide right from the beginning to the end (including removing Libre): http://tecadmin.net/install-apache-openoffice-on-ubuntu-debian/#

When I get to the latter part of step 3 (desktop integration), I get the following error:

```
jdave@eng-tp06-l:~/en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration$ sudo dpkg -i openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.2-9782_all.deb

(Reading database ... 286456 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.2-9782_all.deb ...
Unpacking openoffice-debian-menus (4.1.2-9782) ...
dpkg: error processing archive openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.2-9782_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.2-9782_all.deb
```

Using the command given on the site results in a missing file error as well which is why I modified it to use the entire package name in the folder. I'm relatively new at using Ubuntu so I'd love some help.

Comment: Libreoffice and Openoffice conflict when installed at the same time.

Comment: Looks like,even though I thought I'd completely removed Libre, there were still some remnants causing the issue. I used sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-common and that did it. Thank you!

Comment: Mark it solved with your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libre was the one causing the issue. I thought I had removed it but there were still some remnants. To remove them, I used

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-common
```

and then tried the previous command again and it worked!